# Market cap and stability

Tags: stock-markets

Let SSSS be an arbitrary stock with a significant market cap. Assume SSSS fall sharply (say 30% at pre-market) by reasonable reasons and not something too specific, maybe bad earnings or some twitter users were too toxic for example...

The graphs show that statistically such a company will recover someday (by "significant market cap" I mean top market cap copmanies (say top 50~100)).

Why is this happanning? I'm new to finance and curious why such phenomena occur.

Comment: Because people.

Comment: You can only *buy* the stock for what others are willing to sell for. The demand for the stock at its new lower price is going to outstrip the supply of people willing to sell for so low, resulting in the price climbing again.

Comment: Share price goes up when there's more net buying volume than selling volume and vice versa.  Not all companies recover their market cap.  Some even go bankrupt.

Comment: This "SSSS" looks like PayPal Holdings, Inc. (NASDAQ: PYPL).